# [React][MUI] Warning: Cannot update a component while rendering a different component

Tags: material-ui

I am using AutoComplete(MUI) to create a country selector, but I got the error message below.

```
Warning: Cannot update a component (`CountrySelectorPopup`) while rendering a different component (`ForwardRef(Autocomplete)`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `ForwardRef(Autocomplete)`
```

This error happends only when I have a setState `setState(filtered[filtered.length - 1])` inside of the function.

```
const handleFilterOptions = useCallback((
    options: TermObject[],
    params: FilterOptionsState<TermObject>
  ) => {
    const filtered = filter(options, params);
    setState(filtered[filtered.length - 1]);
    return filtered;
  }, [1]);
```

And I pass this function to AutoComplete filterOptions.

```
<Autocomplete
  clearOnBlur
  fullWidth
  freeSolo
  onChange={(_e, _newValue) => setValue("")}
  onInputChange={(_e, newValue) => setInputValue(newValue)}
  value={value}
  inputValue={inputValue}
  open={true}
  filterOptions={handleFilterOptions}...
```

I believe this is AutoComplete related error, but could anyone tell me why this happens because it doesn't seems like a bad setState call to me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move out `setState` function from `handleFilterOptions`.
Pass `setState` inside `onInputChange` prop.

All because of render behavior `Autocomplete` component.